# Is it required to merge hard drives when you install Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I've decided to install Ubuntu after having problems with Windows.

I read that in Ubuntu you get a root folder. So, is it required to merge all hard drives?

Comment: What ? How would you merge hard drives ? LVM? RAID ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think she means partitions like C:, D: etc.

Answer (score 2):

How it works is by mounting the partitions in logical locations within the operating system.

On Windows they use locations labelled C:, D: etc for each partition or hard drive and these appear separately.

In Linux there is a single filesystem tree and all partitions/drives are mounted on it somewhere. In Ubuntu you may mount a partition at `/home` to have all of the home directories stored on one partition or a separate hard drive

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu, Linux, and all Unix variants have a *unified view* on all (active/mounted) file systems which is not the same as having a *single unified* file system.

The Linux kernel “mounts” file systems over arbitrary directories in its unified view, thus extending the view with the contents of the newly mounted file system. When a process modifies something in that branch of the view the kernel will take care to modify the underlying file system accordingly.

You can therefore split the content of the unified view over multiple file systems, partitions, and drives.

See [Wikipedia on “Mount”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) for a different explanation.

---

(In DOS/Windows file systems used to exist in distinct name spaces labelled with drive letters. Since NT, Windows has a unified file system view like Linux/Unix but kept the drive letters as labels to the actual mount points for historical reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David's and Pat's answers; however, I also want to point out that installing Ubuntu generally requires creating at least one *new* partition that's dedicated to Ubuntu. This partition will hold the Ubuntu root (`/`) directory, as well as any subdirectory that is not used as a mount point for another filesystem (partition, removable device, virtual device, etc.).

In some cases, the Ubuntu installer can shrink one or more existing partitions in an automated way, making room for the partition(s) that Ubuntu needs. In other cases, you must do this yourself. Ubuntu installation tutorials help guide you through the process, so I won't go into details here, especially since those details can vary from one system to another. Several factors can affect how you repartition the disk(s), including:

- How many physical disks you have (note that the drive letters in Windows refer to partitions, so you might have fewer physical disks that Windows drive letters)
- How many partitions exist on your disk(s), what filesystem(s) they hold, and other details how how they're laid out
- What partition table type(s) your disk(s) use (MBR vs. GPT), which for Windows is tightly linked to boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI)
- What other OS(es) are installed -- you note Windows in your question, but if you have others installed, that's important, too
- What *versions* of other OS(es) are installed -- this can be especially important for Windows, since there are version-specific quirks that can affect partitioning

If you need more help after reading an installation guide or two, be sure to provide as many of these details as you can in subsequent questions.